# Apache POI getFontAt (XLS)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to parse an .xls document. Therefore i need to see if a particular letter is bold / italic / etc.

As far as i know there are 3 Methods to get what i want via apache.POI:

```
- HSSFFont font = workbook.getFontAt((short)i); (This one iterates
through the whole document)
- HSSFRichTextString s = (HSSFRichTextString)cell.getRichStringCellValue(); This one looks at
a given index, which should be best for me and
- http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html this one won't work for me, because i dont want the style of a given Cell, i want the formatting of a given single letter.
```

This is what i tried so far (Also taking into account several posts about this on stackoverflow):

```
if(this.formatFlag) {
                        boolean boldFlag = false;
                        boolean italicFlag = false;

                        HSSFRichTextString s = (HSSFRichTextString)cell.getRichStringCellValue();
                        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                            int x = s.getFontAtIndex(i);
                            System.out.println("FormatCode: " + x + "-" + s.getString().charAt(i));
                        }
```

When letting this run over a .xls document i tend to get tons of "0" where there is actually bold text, which tells me it isn't working. Also i sometimes get 15/16, when there is only normal text. So i seem to not use this function correctly. Any ideas?

Also: Where can i find an exact list of the format IDs? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the font on the Cell Style that applies to the cell? That's what get used by default, except when other formatting overrides it

Comment: I have pressed STRING + A and set the complete table t the same font, same size, same alignment, etc. Everything is formatted the same except for some letters or cells to be bold. 
This one (System.out.println(workbook.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex()).getBoldweight());) Gives me the perfect cell value if its bold or not. But how can i get the value corresponding to each letter of the cell? ...

Comment: Iterate over the runs in the RichTextString. If they're styled, fetch those, if not use the cell's cell style?

Comment: I actually didn't know how to do that, because the API documentation isn't really helpful. Thanks a lot for the tip, i got it working now and will post my working code here in case anybody else needs it. :)

Comment: Suggested improvements to documentation are always gratefully received! If you can think of a good way to explain it, open a bug for the project and detail there the improvement

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gagravarr for his tip this is a solution that works perfectly fine:

```
HSSFRichTextString s = (HSSFRichTextString) cell.getRichStringCellValue();
                        int wbBold = workbook.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex()).getBoldweight();
                        boolean wbItalic = workbook.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex()).getItalic();

                        if(wbBold == Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD) {
                            data = "<b>" + s.getString() + "</b>";
                        }
                        else if(wbItalic) {
                            data = "<i>" + s.getString() + "</i>";
                        }
                        else {
                            for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                                HSSFFont font = workbook.getFontAt(s.getFontAtIndex(i));

                                if(font.getItalic() && !italicFlag) {
                                    data += "<i>" + s.getString().charAt(i);
                                    italicFlag = true;
                                }
                                else if (!font.getItalic() && italicFlag) {
                                    data += "</i>" + s.getString().charAt(i);
                                    italicFlag = false;
                                }                           
                                else if((font.getBoldweight() == Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD) && !boldFlag) {
                                    data += "<b>" + s.getString().charAt(i);
                                    boldFlag = true;
                                }
                                else if ((font.getBoldweight() != Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD) && boldFlag) {
                                    data += "<b/>" + s.getString().charAt(i);
                                    boldFlag = false;
                                }
                                else {
                                    data += s.getString().charAt(i);
                                }
                            }

                            if(boldFlag) {
                                data += "</b>";
                            }
                            if(italicFlag) {
                                data += "</i>";
                            }
                        }
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The getFontAtIndex returns just an index to the font.
Use the `getFontAt(short idx)` from the corresponding workbook and use its bold weight.

Comment: I cannot do that, because i am iterating over the workbook cell by cell and handle the data corresponding to the cell type. So once i am inside a cell which i actually want to parse i have the cell.getRichStringCellValue(). After that i need to look at this string which letter is bold or not.
Even if i could use that solution: Why doesn't my code work and gives me 0's instead of 6 for bold text in every case?